# Ajax POST Requests return int instead of string

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have the following JS code:

```
var dataString = "action=validateUsername"+
         "&username="+usernameRegi+
         "&lang="+lang;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "function.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(result)
    {           
        var expl=result.split("|");

                if(expl[0]=="1")
            alert("1");

                else if(expl[0]=="99")
        alert("99");
    }
});
```

This is my function.php

```
if($_POST["action"]=="validateUsername")
{
    $username=$_POST["username"];
    $lang=$_POST["lang"];

    $sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM user where userName='".$username."'";
    $sqlQuery = mysql_query($sqlSelect);
    $rowCount = mysql_num_rows($sqlQuery);

    if($rowCount>0)
    {
    if($lang=="BM")
        echo "99|My msgA.";
    else
        echo "99|My msgB.";
    }
    else
    {
    if($lang=="BM")
        echo "1|My msgC.";
    else
        echo "1|My msgD.";  
    }
}
```

The problem is, my ajax request never alert 1 or 99 on success. And I found the problem is expl[0]==1 instead of expl[0]=="1".

When I turn my code to this one, it run smooth.:-

```
if(expl[0]==1)
alert("1");

else if(expl[0]==99)
alert("99");
```

This is happen only when I upload my code to the server. No problem on the localhost. What is the problem, is there any setting on the server that cause that problem?

Could anybody explain me, what is happening here?

Comment: Not part of your question.  But as an FYI. There is no more support for mysql_* functions, they are officially deprecated, no longer maintained and will be removed in the future. You should update your code with PDO or MySQLi to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 4):

It's because:

When you assign a numeric value to a variable, do not put quotes around the value. If you put quotes around a numeric value, it will be treated as text.

Answer (score 0):

while passing values and returning them from function make sure not to add quotes to int values. or add function below to check / convert them to int

function isint( $mixed )
{
    return ( preg_match( '/^\d*$/'  , $mixed) == 1 );
}